# Setting up a private local server, that is PHP and SQL capable

Tags: php, sql, testing

(Please note I am completely new to this, don't be mean)

I have a laptop (running a clean install of Ubuntu), how can I set up a local testing server that any computer on my network can access? It has to be SQL and PHP capable

Comment: Depends on which SQL dbms you want to use...

Comment: Xampp? But this question is still off topic.

Comment: What options are there?

Comment: Use MySQL: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Answer (score 3):

Ok So You want to setup Localhost with apche2 , mysql and phpmyadmin ?

**First install apache2 using command line**

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

**then install php and other stuffs**

```
sudo apt-get install php5,php5-cli,php5-mysql,php5-curl
```

**Now you need to install Mysql server**

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

This will ask username and password for mysql server

**then install phpmyadmin**

```
 sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Provide mysql credential while installing and here you go .. :-) .